# Regex to find and replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

```
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'text_to_change');
```

How can I replace `'text_to_change'` to something else in PHP. I think I should use `preg_replace` but the true is that I have no idea how to use regex.

The result I need:

```
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'some_text');
```

I need it to do with regex no other solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like code itself already... What is `_e`? Some sort of templating translation function?

Comment: text_to_change is a variable or just a simple text? And you are messing up things with single quotes. It should be `"Don't change this..."` or `'Don\'t change this...'`

Comment: @putvande, yes exactly.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, uhh, my bad. This is just an example and is very easy to miss it when is no syntax highlighting. ^_^ Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex would match the text inside the second single quotes. Just replace the matched string with  `some_text`.

```
(?<= \')[^']*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/23)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = <<<'EOT'
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'text_to_change');
EOT;
$pattern = "~(?<= \')[^']*~";
$replacement = 'some_text';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'some_text');
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<= \')` Lookbehind is actually used to look after a string which matches a particular pattern. In our case, it looks after the string `'`(ie, space followed by a single quote). Second quotes satisfy this condition. So the regex engine sets the matching marker only after to the second single quote.
- `[^']*` Matches any character not of single quote, zero or more times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
_e\('.*',\s*'\K[^']*
```

[**Explanation**](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=_e%5C%28%27.*%27%2C%5Cs*%27%5CK%5B%5E%27%5D*&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

**Example**:

```
$text = <<<DATA
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'text_to_change');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'text_to_change');
DATA;

$text = preg_replace("/_e\('.*',\s*'\K[^']*/", 'some_text', $text);
echo $text;
```

**Output**:

```
_e('Don\'t change this 1...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this extra...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this te...', 'some_text');
_e('Don\'t change this text...', 'some_text');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace`, but there's not much point if you're just trying to change out a fixed string. Why not just use `str_replace`:

```
$newString = str_replace('text_to_change', 'some_text', $oldString);
```

It would be worth using `preg_replace` if you're worried that the text `'text_to_change'` might appear somewhere else. In this case I guess you could write a regex to match those specific lines. This might look something like:

```
$pattern = "^_e\('(.+)', 'text_to_change'\);$";
$newString = preg_replace($pattern, "_e('\1', 'some_text');", $oldString);
```

If you're using Linux it might be easier to use `find` and `sed` from the command-line rather than whip up a custom PHP script:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -ir "s/_e\('(.+)', 'text_to_change'\);/_e('\1', 'some_text');/" {} \;
```

Here we use `find` to locate all files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`) with a name like `*.php`. We then call `sed` to change in-place (`-i`) the files given.

Comment: No. I know how to replace this way, but the problem is that I have in different locations and I need to replace it only when is within _e() function.

Comment: No problem: I've updated the answer to include some regex goodness. (Make sure you have your code in source control before hitting go!)